# Скачивание множества файлов в разных потоках через python

Tags: python, многопоточность, requests, beautiful-soup

Для скачивания манги с сайта [mangalib](https://mangalib.me), надо каждый раз нажимать на отдельную главу, было очень лениво нажимать 145 раз, поэтому был придуман скрипт, который делает запрос на этот сайт, парсит ссылочки с кнопок для скачивания глав, и скачивает их сам, всё было бы ок, но скачивает он их последовательно, соответственно на 40 глав заняло минут 6-7, хотел через потоки ускорить данный процесс выделением скачивания главы в отдельный поток, но видимо что-то тут пошло не так и 5 из 145 глав скачиваются нормально, а остальные видимо толи не успевают, толи что то еще, но в общем они не скачиваются и скрипт заканчивается, можно ли как это исправить или возможно по-другому применить потоки?

P.S. без всех `headers` не даёт ссылки

[Ссылочка на ту мангу, с которой проводился эксперимент](https://mangalib.me/toukyou-kushu)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from threading import Thread
import requests
import time


def get_response(url):
        headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'authority': 'mangalib.me',
        'method': 'GET',
        'path': '/toukyou-kushu',
        'scheme': 'https',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1079327140.1550150668; _ym_uid=1550150668838523892; _ym_d=1550150668; cartalyst_sentinel=eyJpdiI6InA5VUVLTnBQcGdXYnZZcW5NckFjRmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidHpaZ2ZiMEdEWFRBc212WDA1YU9zT2t1cmtVZ0FHR05leVNHUTlEVkVjeXJVdm9oc2VQenNYZXcxMm1zQ2R6MyIsIm1hYyI6IjVjYTc3MWM1YzRhMGRmNTY4ZjJlNTc0YThkY2I0NmJiMDMwNDg0Y2E5ODYyNzRiN2QxNGZlZWVmNmMzOTI1MGQifQ%3D%3D; __cfduid=d471cc8dbecfdfe2b40bcc9e1288d88311551966826; _gid=GA1.2.615184832.1555103456; _ym_isad=1; _ym_wasSynced=%7B%22time%22%3A1555804720080%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22eu%22%3A0%7D%2C%22bkParams%22%3A%7B%7D%7D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImJaODBRRURnc1pRTlpHb0k2djliNUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQUZXR2R1akhDOHpRMlFDMUliNGhJbEYrUXozWGVGaVRwTlRBMllKc3dtcStITkJSV1wvWjdjQmlRMmlMSzl3OXJTQktFXC82ZnQzRTdhbVZ2SU1LU0l4UT09IiwibWFjIjoiYzNhODc2NTk4Y2ExNWQ4M2Y4NTFhZDE4ZDBkYmMxNzRkMWQwZDcxMWYwYmNkMmJlMzg1NzI2ZWE0NjVmYjAyMSJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkxZTG9UWEFIODlWRDRtcjBWdXJNNGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWGF3SU9GN0RYaGwrSmJzQUJzY0szTXF6dEZCWm5XQ1RyVGZiUnNhU1hVN3BaTlpqSFwvc1NETnNIV1VqQSsxakRDMlJwTjBBYndQb1wvXC81RDBYcVp5NHc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImJlZjdiOTIyNGNmYTdhMzI0MDkwZGRhYmU1MzBjZTkwYjBiODUxNzY4NjkyZDMzZjYwMmQ4ZmVkMzBlZjVhZTkifQ%3D%3D; _ym_visorc_21237529=b; _gat_gtag_UA_27663466_6=1',
        'dnt': '1',
        'referer': 'https://mangalib.me/bookmark',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        }
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        #for key, value in r.request.headers.items():
        #    print(key+": "+value)
        return r

def download(url, title, directory):
    ufr = get_response(url)
    f = open(r'' + directory + title + '.zip', 'wb')
    f.write(ufr.content)
    f.close()



url = 'https://mangalib.me/toukyou-kushu'#str(input('Введите url сайта: \n'))
directory = 'D:/manga/'#str(input('Введите директорию для скачивания через /: \n'))




#https://mangalib.me/toukyou-kushu
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_response(url).text, 'html.parser')

for chapter in soup.find_all('div', class_='chapter-item'):
        url_download = chapter.find('div', class_='chapter-item__actions').find('a', class_='chapter-item__icon link-default').get('href')
        title = chapter.find('div', class_='chapter-item__name').find('a', class_='link-default').get('href')[20:].replace('/', '-')
        thread = Thread(target=download, args=(url_download, title, directory))
        thread.start()
```

Comment: Сайт скорее всего ограничивает количество запросов от одного источника. Как он это определяет и можно ли это обойти, отдельный момент. Если не ломиться напролом, то следует сделать 5 потоков для скачивания и передавать им URLs через Queue. Будет в 5 раз быстрее, чем последовательно.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду пробовать)

Comment: Есть довольно много фреймворков, которые как раз заточены на скачивание сайтов.
Из самых распространённых Scrapy, Grab.

Многие сайты борются со скачиванием. Хотя бы потому что скачиванием создаётся изрядная нагрузка на сервер.